# LINQ get max of Amount but return name

Tags: linq

I have 2 columns
Name and Amount

I like the linq to return the Name based on who has the Maximum Amount.

So far I have the following:

```
    string name = (from nm in bg
           select nm.Name).Max(Amount);
```

which obviously will not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string name = (from nm in bg
               where nm.Amount == bg.Max(i=>i.Amount)
           select nm.Name)
```

or

```
string name = (from nm in bg
               orderby nm.Amount desc
           select nm.Name).First()
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest approach I can think is as this (find max amount, then find item which has max amount, two way traversing, and is O(n)):

```
decimal amount = bg.Max(x=>x.Amount);
var name = bg.First(x=>x.Amount == amount).Name; // O(n)
```

Also you can do:

```
// O(n^2) in worst case, O(n) in best case
bg.First(x=>x.Amount == bg.Max(x=>x.Amount)).Name;
```

Or

```
bg.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Amount).First().Name; // O(n log n) in all situation
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
bg.OrderByDescending(nm => nm.Amount).First().Name
```

will get what you want, but will throw if `bg` is empty. If this is a problem, use

```
var topNm = bg.OrderByDescending(nm => nm.Amount).FirstOrDefault();
```

and check `topNm` for nullity.